# How can I silently push an apk and get it installed by android device policy using android management api?

Tags: google-play, mdm, android-management-api, android-enterprise

I am trying to push an APK to the device and get it installed by Android device policy (Device owner) rather than pushing application from play store.

I am able to push applications that are available on play store using 
 device policy

---

```
{
  "packageName": string,
  "installType": enum(InstallType),
  "lockTaskAllowed": boolean,
  "defaultPermissionPolicy": enum(PermissionPolicy),
  "permissionGrants": [
    {
      object(PermissionGrant)
    }
  ],
  "managedConfiguration": {
    object
  },
  "disabled": boolean,
  "minimumVersionCode": number,
  "delegatedScopes": [
    enum(DelegatedScope)
  ],
  "managedConfigurationTemplate": {
    object(ManagedConfigurationTemplate)
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can push an APK to the device and get it installed by android device policy ?

Comment: post some code please [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to use the Android Management API to install an APK that is not in Play.

However you can publish your app in Play and [restrict it to one or more enterprises](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6145139), this way your app won't be visible publicly. This is also explained [here](https://developers.google.com/android/management/apps#upload_your_own_app_to_the_google_play_store) in the documentation of the Android Management API.