# Self-hosted/EMM hosted private app's via Android Management API

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-enterprise

Is it possible to use AMAPI to publish self-hosted/private app's to a device that is either using work profile or is fully managed without using the play store?

I am confused because what the answer i'm seeing in the following post doesn't jive with Google's documentation.
[How can I silently push an apk and get it installed by android device policy using android management api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56287961/how-can-i-silently-push-an-apk-and-get-it-installed-by-android-device-policy-usi)

User "Fred" in the above link says this operation is not possible however, the documentation at this website lists it as "Optional"
https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements?api=clouddpx#313-self-hosted-private-app-management

Second question, using AMAPI requires the Android Device Policy on a device, can we use a custom DPC in conjunction with ADP to publish our private apps given that they are hosted via an EMM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no!

The options you have is to use the play store/ private play store if you are using Android Management API.

Or integrate iFrame of Play Store - https://developers.google.com/android/management/apps

Self hosted APKs are again installed via Play store but it's hosted on your cloud.

As of now there is no way to install Apps without using play store!